# How to attach OllyDbg to hidden process?

Tags: process, reverse-engineering, hidden, ollydbg

I am trying to reverse engineer a program that requires a serial key to run. The problem is that when i want to attach OllyDbg to the program, the process is basically not coming up. When i opened task manager to try and find the process, i could easily find it. Can someone explain why this happens, and how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with permissions. Try open OllyDbg as an Administrator, then you should be able to see the process and attach to it.

Comment: I have tried this, and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: pass link to exe i will tell a look